# selecting position with respect to parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML did some research in w3school but not clear about how put image on this three different position on this background image in one div. I marked the position I need to put the image. The div will cover entire page in webkit and moz based browser. Consider any width and height of div. How you fixed position with respect to your considered width and height. I can't put background image to entire html or body or etc. It have to in one div or section only.

[image]

```
<div id="page1" style={"background:url('http://s27.postimg.org/r5v9ymd77/pg3bgl.png');background-size:cover;}">
    <span class="">Page 1</span>
    <div class="">
        <!-- Content Goes Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple way to achieve that using relative CSS positioning.

You can use a background div, and inside of it place the divs you need.

```css
    *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    .background{
      background:url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/1600/nature');
      background-size:cover;
      height:100vh;
      width:100%;
    }

    .img1,
    .img2,
    .img3{
      position:relative;
      width:300px;
      height:150px;
      background:url('http://placehold.it/300x150');
    }

    .img1{
      top:20px;
      left:350px;
    }

    .img2{
      top:150px;
      left: 20px;
    }

    .img3{
      top:350px;
      left:150px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="img1"></div>
  <div class="img2"></div>
  <div class="img3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: answer you put is what i am looking for.but still have some query,how you are positioning top left px value for img1,img2,img3 are you calculating it random value.how do i understand say new position value with respect to selected div.

Comment: @delta12 what do you mean exactly by selected div? You want the div to change position if clicked? Maybe you mean using percentage values instead of fixed pixels? like `top: 10%` for example based on `.background` div width

Comment: no not div position.i marked 3 position inside div with background image on it.now i insert one more image between 2nd & 3rd image.it have some gap initially when i view in browser.but i came to condition that my 3rd img should  just below 2nd img with no gap while viewing it on browser.how to do that

Comment: @delta12 You can add as many images as you want, even between the ones that are already coded. To achieve different positioning you just have to adjust the top and left (or right eventually) rules in your CSS according to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you can have a look at multiple images backgrounds, here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Answer (score 0):

i would set up the html like this:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="image1" style=""></div>
  <div id="image2" style=""></div>
  <div id="image3" style=""></div>
  <div>
    <p>Text in navbar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For each id "imageX" you could set a background-image then. And with display: inline-block, width and position you can put them where you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that.
You can set the `position` of your div to `absolute` and adjust it to the position you'd like it to be

```
 #div1 {
 position : absolute;
 left : 100px;
 top : 200px;     
 }
```

You can also set the position to `relative`and have your div placed relatively to its normal position.

You can check this for [more information on the position property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp);

Answer (score 0):

You could insert DIV within DIV. And you could position DIV using the **top** and **left** style attributes.

```
    <div id="page1" style="{background:url('http://s27.postimg.org/r5v9ymd77/pg3bgl.png');background-size:cover;}">
        <span class="">Page 1</span>
        <div id="subpanel_1" style="top:20px; left:102px;>
            <!-- Content Goes Here -->
        </div>
        <div id="subpanel_2" style="top:200px; left:50px;>
            <!-- Content Goes Here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Of course, instead of writing the style definitions inline, better put them in a separate <style>…</style> block.